# how to handle half open socket in middle of transfer?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

```
/*Basic Things has been done.*/
/*Like setting connection and receiving */
namespace bar = boost::asio::error;
void doWrite(char* buffer, size_t size_) {
    boost::asio::async_write_some(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer ,size), boost::bind(&Handler, this, bar::error, bar::bytes_transferred));
}

/*handler*/
void handler(/*parameters*/)
{
}
```

while my server is continuously transferring the data. sometimes client gets crash /*purposely */. 
    `errorCode.message()` gives error of `boost::asio::error::bad_descriptor` and whole program crashes. 
i have copied the program from boost chat server example.

if server is transmitting let say 1024 bytes and while writing client close in middle of writing of 1024 bytes. whole program crashes.

More Technical Wording:
how to handle half open socket in middle of transfer?

Comment: _"whole program crashes"_ Okay what actually happens? What diagnostic does your debugger report for the occasion? And present your [MCVE].

Comment: A bad descriptor error is not caused by a half-open socket. It is caused, usually, by closing the socket and then continuing to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to do all operations either catching `system_error` or receiving (and checking) the `error_code`.

As you say, you already receive the `boost::asio::error::bad_descriptor` code, so I expect the program termination results because of a subsequent action on the same socket that throws.

Look for the overloads that take a `boost::system::error_code&` parameter (like e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/close.html).

Comment: i was doing post operation of data transmission on same socket, even though i received `bad_file_descriptor`.